# ajax call not working in android application using phonegap

Tags: android, jquery, ajax, cordova, phonegap-plugins

I am using phonegap for creating the apk file for android application. Below is the code of my `index.html`

```
<html>
<head><title>Test application</title>
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function(){
            $("#submitValue").on("click",function(){
                alert("");
                getServerResponse($("#userValue").val());
            });
        });

        function getServerResponse(userValue){
            var serverUrl="http://xxx.site.net/xxx/Hello/"+ userValue +"?format=json";
                $.ajax({
                    url:serverUrl,
                    type:"GET",
                    contentType:"application/json",
                    dataType:"jsonp",

                    success:function(data){
                        alert("Success");
                        $("#serverResponse").html(data.Result);
                    },

                    error:function(){
                        alert("error");
                    }
                });
            };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div>
        <h3>Enter your name and click submit</h3>
    </div>

    <div>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter your Name" id="userValue"/>
        <input type="button" id="submitValue" value="Submit"/>
    </div>

    <div id="serverResponse"></div>
</body>
```

This works perfectly when i open using a browser, but when the app is opened and submit is clicked, i get the alert for click, but nothing happens after that. neither success alert not error alert comes when i click the submit button via android app

Comment: May be cross origin request ? Look the console, to see what's happening in the network

Comment: @BipBip in any browser its working fine
and only for cross origin request i added dataType:"jsonp"
The problem occurs only when its an android app

Comment: In your config.xml , do you have a line like this <access origin="*" /> ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give permission for INTERNET in AndroidManifest.xml file.
Include the line below to the AndroidManifest.xml

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
```